# converting char values in string to int for multiplication

Tags: java, char, int, type-conversion

Good evening everyone.

I can't seem to figure this out. I have written a function to break down a simple ascii art txt file and convert it to a form of number representation where the number specifies how many times the proceeding character value were scanned in from a source file. IE: ### was converted to (3,#,nextVal,nextChar).

As part of an assignment for class, I need to essentially reverse the previous operation back into an ascii art style. How should I go about converting the numbers within into int values that could be used to specify desired number of the following char? Here's what I've been trying thus far

```
public static void numRepToImage(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintStream out=new PrintStream(input);
    Scanner in=new Scanner(output);
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String s=in.nextLine();
        for(int x=0; x<s.length()-5; x+=4) {
            char[] ch = new char[s.charAt(x)];
            for(int y=0; y<=s.length()-1; y++) { 
                int z = (int) (ch[x] - '0');
                out.print(z*s.charAt(y));
            }

        }
        out.println();
```

This code compiles, but I receive an array index out of bounds exception also. I apologize for my newness to java still.

Comment: Look at this statement: `char[] ch = new char[s.charAt(x)]` - what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I'll start from the beginning: It seems that you've mixed up the `input` and `output`. As far as I understand, you should read from the `input` and write to the `output`.

Comment: You're correct, however this is a function directly following one in which I brought in an input file and exported a result file. This function is to take the result file back in, convert, and output (supposed to be) the same ascii art file that I began with. Sorry, it's a bit difficult to explain more clearly.

Comment: @JonSkeet That was my attempt to form an array for the "number" values from the `String` that represents each line from my originally broken-down ascii art file. I was hoping to convert those elements into `int` values. I tried to base that segment of code off of a few examples I came across when searching for proper code. Obviously, I didn't get it right haha.

Comment: @jgillespie: But you've created an array whose *length* is the UTF-16 code unit value in `s` at position `x`. What size of array did you intend to create? You might want to break out pen and paper at this point, and try to work out what you would do as a human, then codify that.